# Cross Platform App Development with Corona

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, coronasdk

I am wanting to build a cross-platform mobile app for iOS and android devices. I have never tried making a mobile app before and was thinking of using Corona SDK. I went to the Corona site to download the SDK and I have a few questions. First, it says that "Due to Apple's restrictions, you cannot build for iOS on Windows". Does this mean I can only build an Android app or does it mean I have to publish it to the app store using an Apple computer? Seeing that Corona is cross platform I think it would be stupid if you had to use an Apple computer to get the cross-platform benefit of Corona. Second, do I have to subscribe to Corona to be able to put my app on the app store or can I do this for free with the free version of the Corona SDK. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.anscamobile.com/pricing/whysubscribe.html?ref=home) about distribution.  Yes, you need a mac to use iOS because of Apple's restrictions.

Comment: I need a mac to develop a iOS app or just to publish it?

Comment: Need it to develop:  From the website "Please note: Due to Apple's restrictions, you cannot build for iOS on Windows."

Comment: ok so I could just write the code on a PC then when it is complete just build it on a mac since they both use the same language (lua)

Comment: @ewein: That would be a terrible idea. No matter how cross-platform something claims to be, shipping a product on a system, or at least an OS, that you have never tested it on is a path that only ends in tears.

Comment: Well I would obviously test it on the MAC before building it.